# Python CNN im2col function doesn't make sense

Tags: python, convolution, flatten

In CNN Convolution learning, im2col function code is not understood.

```
def im2col(input_data, filter_h, filter_w, stride=1, pad=0):
    N, C, H, W = input_data.shape
    out_h = (H + 2*pad - filter_h)//stride + 1
    out_w = (W + 2*pad - filter_w)//stride + 1
    img = np.pad(input_data, [(0,0), (0,0), (pad, pad), (pad, pad)], 'constant')
    col = np.zeros((N, C, filter_h, filter_w, out_h, out_w))

#I DON'T KNOW!
for y in range(filter_h):
        y_max = y + stride*out_h
        for x in range(filter_w):
            x_max = x + stride*out_w
            col[:, :, y, x, :, :] = img[:, :, y:y_max:stride, x:x_max:stride]

    col = col.transpose(0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3).reshape(N*out_h*out_w, -1)
    return col
```

Q1. I don't know why the input data(img) is converted to six dimensions(col). Why are you converting like that?

Q2. Python syntax is not familiar. So,I don't understand the syntax of lines 9-13.
Can you explain it in C / C ++ / JAVA?

I tried a lot to understand. Help me.

I'm sorry about the weird grammar. :(

Have a nice day and thank you all!